# Occasionally Internet disconnect on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, remote-desktop

Edit 1: I have found the problem(hope so),and edited the question to be more precise.
Sometimes the internet connection on my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop is disconnected(even when I'm using it directly or through remote connection), I have to manually click on the Internet connection icon of the taskbar, and select Wired connection 1 to make it connected again. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this in terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install ethtool
sudo ethtool eth0
```

still have the same issue,

copy the necessary files from the system and install new [Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Comment: I have tried your solution, I will post its result after a while of testing

Comment: I still have the issue despite trying the above command